# How can I display only selected options of a fild type ManyToMany - django

Tags: django, many-to-many, manytomanyfield

Good morning, I need to display the values selected in the manytomany field named "sfide" in a table I will build with html, how can I do it? thanks

I also attach the image of the class "Profilo" with the ManyToMany field "sfide"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2y8Z.png)

Comment: Good morning. You should never put code within images. I get you probably want it to look pretty, but that is what the code blocks are for. [Here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362/13643492) is a link explaining it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer:

```
            <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <h4>Sfide Scelte</h4>
                </td>
            </tr>
            {% for sfida in user.profile.sfide.all %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ sfida.sfida }}</td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </table>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).